# Deleting records from Hive Target table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a target table A from which i want to delete 3 duplicate records. I found that delete from table where id = 1 does not work in Hive (which is straightforward)

In turn, what im doing now is :

```
Step 1: Create a copy table of the target table
```

```
Step 2: Insert into copy table select * from target where id not in (1,2,3)
```

```
step 3: Truncate target table
```

```
step 4: Insert into target table select * from copy table
```

Is there any approach which is more straightforward than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert overwrite from itself:

```
--for partitioned table
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

--If you are on Qubole
set hive.allow.move.on.s3=true;

insert overwrite table target partition (col1,col2)
select * from target where id not in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. If its a partitioned table, then it would be insert overwrite table tabl1 partition (column1,column2) select * from target where id not in (1,2,3) ?

Comment: @jahan Yes. Add added that in the answer

Comment: Thank you so much.